# foreach $_POST update depending on $key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, foreach

I'm trying to update my database with a foreach loop. Each time the loop is run, two rows will need to be changed, however the database updates both rows with the same data. My php code for the form is:

```
<input name="poles<?php echo $curtains['room_curtains_id']; ?>" type="radio" class="calc" id="<?php echo $poles['curtains_poles_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $poles['curtains_poles_price']; ?>,<?php echo $poles['curtains_poles_id']; ?>">
<input name="pleats<?php echo $curtains['room_curtains_id']; ?>" type="radio" class="calc" id="<?php echo $pleats['curtains_pleats_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $pleats['curtains_pleats_price']; ?>,<?php echo $pleats['curtains_pleats_id']; ?>">
```

When posting, my return is:

```
Array
(
    [poles1] => 0.00,1
    [pleats1] => 40.00,2
    [poles2] => 120.00,2
    [pleats2] => 0.00,1
    [poles3] => 150.00,3
    [pleats3] => 40.00,2
)
```

Now when it comes to updating the database I am using the following code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$new_value = explode(",", $value);

if (strpos($key, 'poles')!==false) {

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE basket SET product_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[1])."', line_price= '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[0])."' WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND plot_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."' AND product_type='Poles' AND rooms_curtains_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'");

}

if (strpos($key, 'pleats')!==false) {

$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE basket SET product_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[1])."', line_price= '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[0])."' WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND plot_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."' AND product_type='Pleats' AND rooms_curtains_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'");
}

}
```

- Note the only difference in the two queries is the `product_type`.

When I run this, the database is updated correctly for `product_type='Poles' ($result)` but with the same information for `product_type='Pleats' ($result2)`, where it should be updating using the key `pleats1`,`pleats2`,`pleats3`.

Comment: You never filtered the `$key` variables. You tell the MySQL: `Update me the rows where product_type is 'Pleats' with the variable $key`, but you never specify what $key should contain

Comment: Your query takes in too many input, might be a better idea for you to show us the values to be printed for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handle the conditions for the MySQL resultset, but you never handled the conditions in your PHP code. You expect magically the MySQL to understand when you specify column with value `Pleats`, to search in your `foreach()` loop for `%pleats%`, but it will never happen, because that are two different things.

The mysql query will be executed as many times, as the iterations in the loop are. In your case - both queries will be executed 6 times with each `$key`.

If you want to update the rows which has `product_type='Pleats'` with the `$key` which contains `pleats`, you should tell the PHP so. It's no more on MySQL level.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $new_value = explode(",", $value);

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE basket SET product_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[1])."', line_price= '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[0])."' WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND plot_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."' AND product_type='Poles' AND rooms_curtains_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'");

    if (strpos($key, 'pleats')!==false) {
        $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE basket SET product_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[1])."', line_price= '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_value[0])."' WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND plot_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."' AND product_type='Pleats' AND rooms_curtains_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Royal Bg, I've updated my question with the changes to your code,  but now neither result appears to run

Comment: It works fine for me, I just copied your code, but changed mysql query with ECHO, in order to print the queries, and it print the queries as much times as the condition is met. I.e. if 2 radio buttons for Pleats are checked, just 2 times the query is ran

Comment: The database requires the $key to be int(11). That's why the query wasn't updating. I've tried using $intkey = strtr($key,"poles",""); but this doesn't seem to strip the text from the $key

Comment: preg_match or `$intKey = strrev($key); $intKey=$intKey[0]`. In newer version of PHP you should be able to directly specify `$intKey = strrev($key)[0]` or `$intKey = str_replace('poles', '', $key)`